# Is "Millions more" the same as "More than millions"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

1) I want to know the exact meaning of "Millons more".
ex) The famine killed nearly forty-five million people, and millions more died from disease.

Does the "millions more" mean "more than millions of people" or "addiontional millions of people(to the previous number, that is, forty-five million people)"?

2) How about this?
ex) Millions more have wallowed in the break-up of his marriage after revelations that he fathered a son with a maid.
Is the "Millions more" in this sentence also the same as that of 1)?

3) How about this?
ex) The retail rollout that began in May 2017 is now complete, meaning there are hundreds more locations (384, to be exact!)

Comment: 45 million (one thing), millions more=other millions, not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

45 million (is the number given), millions more=other millions, not specified as to how many millions exactly.

In a text that says **millions more** (or more millions) some number of millions has already been specified.

**There is no way to tell exactly how many "millions more" this is exactly.**

**millions more** or more millions always means the same thing semantically even if the actual numbers intended by the phrase is not known.

In "Millions more have wallowed in the break-up of his marriage" tells us there were some number of people cited before that.

You don't use "millions more" without previous context.

Whether you use millions more or more millions, both imply an antecedent.

Comment: Don't you think that 'more millions' means 'milions over and above the millions so far' whereas 'millions more' means 'millions over and above some quantity (of any size) so far'?  I have spent two million pounds on my house in Camberley, and I expect to spend more millions in future; I have lost fifty thousand pounds in Bitcoin and I could have lost millions more if I had not been cautious.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Your answer is interesting. I'm curious to find out what other people will think of this.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You are **repeating my answer**:  *I have spent **two million** pounds on my house in Camberley, and I expect to spend **more millions** in future*. two million is mentioned first and then more millions. That is **exactly what I said**!. My answer is very clear . Also, we don't know with more millions how many number of millions we're talking about, do we? I said that, too.

Comment: @Min He has said exactly what I said with both his examples: two million, then more millions (same as millions more) **and** 50 thousand pounds, then, millions more.

Comment: Lambie, you wrote this - "millions more or more millions always means the same thing semantically". I disagreed, and gave examples.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I would like to point out that I did not specifically mention **more millions** in my original answer. The actual question was about **millions more**. It was you who mentioned "more millions". So, my answer is fine. And in your two examples, either one means the same thing. I expect to spend more millions = I expect to spend millions more.